# List files with path and size using terminal

Tags: bash

MY folder structure on mac is as below
Folder-1
  testfile.txt  12 kb
  subfolder
    file2         14 kb
    file3         10 mb
Folder -2
  subfolder-1
     testfile  13 kb
     subfolder 1.1
         textfile.txt   10 kb
         pdffile. file  32 kb 
I want a command to display path ,filename and size of the file in ascending order .
**expectation :**
./Folder-1 /subfolder /file3   10 mb
./Folder -2/subfolder-1/subfolder1.1/pdffile.pdf 32 kb.

I found this **for /r %i in (*) do @echo %i"** on windows  to fetch the files with path ,but along with path i need file size in ascending order in mac.

Please refer attachment[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agi8N.png).

Your Inputs are well appreciated!! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `du`command by using :

`$ du -ah myFolder`

This was mentioned here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88065/sorting-files-according-to-size-recursively

If you really need to filter out folders and keep files only, you can use `find` to take the list of files and pipe the output to `sort` command:

`$ find . -type f -exec du -a {} + | sort -n -r`

source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/22448